# How to perform element-wise addition of n arrays without simply using a for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vectorization

As the title suggests, I am wondering how to use Java to sum *n* (where *n* is an arbitrary number greater than 2) arrays together, in a way that scales as *n* increases.

It's probably easiest to explain with an example. I used the following code to produce 20 length-5 arrays.

```
int n = 20;
int k = 5;

Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer[]> tuplesList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Integer[] tuple = new Integer[k];
    Arrays.setAll(tuple, index -> rand.nextInt(30));
    tuplesList.set(i, tuple);
}
```

Now to the bit I am hoping can be improved. My current method of adding arrays together element-wise consists of simply looping through each array and adding their elements to a cumulative sum.

```
int[] cumSum = new int[k];

for (Integer[] tup : tuplesList) {
    Arrays.setAll(cumSum, ind -> cumSum[ind] + tup[ind]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cumSum));
```

This is of course trivial with only 20 arrays, but can be pretty time-consuming if we had 1,000,000. Is there a better way to do this? I have a vectorised way of summing two arrays element-wise using the `Arrays.setAll` function, but can this be genericised to adding *n* arrays together? Note that there is no requirement for the list of arrays don't have to be stored as an `ArrayList<Integer[]>`, that's just where my mind first went to.

P.S. If anyone wants some example numbers, here's what I got when I ran through my script:

```
[12, 20, 12, 22, 14]
[1, 10, 23, 9, 27]
[3, 2, 17, 24, 11]
[6, 11, 22, 5, 15]
[7, 26, 28, 27, 8]
[10, 23, 2, 15, 7]
[13, 5, 19, 3, 9]
[21, 23, 17, 16, 24]
[4, 20, 6, 14, 14]
[19, 4, 16, 24, 4]
[27, 14, 28, 0, 17]
[27, 20, 3, 8, 29]
[2, 21, 0, 24, 26]
[3, 2, 1, 23, 23]
[11, 11, 15, 26, 17]
[10, 26, 10, 8, 3]
[3, 27, 11, 13, 28]
[1, 29, 26, 3, 14]
[20, 1, 10, 29, 8]
[11, 25, 29, 28, 5]

Output:
[211, 320, 295, 321, 303]
```

Comment: You will always have to traverse all the arrays anyway. I would avoid using a closure here because it's probably not optimal (unless the JIT compiler does a very good job), but in terms of algorithm complexity, there's nothing to gain.

Comment: If you have 1,000,000 arrays, you might want to think about saving memory by using a `ArrayList<int[]>` instead, or maybe an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 1,000,000 arrays, you might want to think about saving memory by using a `ArrayList<int[]>` instead, or maybe an `int[][]`.

If you did change to `int[][]`, the absolute most efficient way to do it is like this:

```
static int[] sum(int[]... input) {
    int maxLen = 0;
    for (int[] arr : input)
        if (arr.length > maxLen)
            maxLen = arr.length;
    int[] sum = new int[maxLen];
    for (int[] arr : input)
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            sum[i] += arr[i];
    return sum;
}
```

The first half can of course be replaced with `maxLen = input[0].length` if it is *absolutely* guaranteed that all arrays are equal length. Since the performance impact of that code is minimal compared to the second half of the code, we might as well keep the first half, even with such a guarantee ([defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)).

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum(
        new int[] { 12, 20, 12, 22, 14 },
        new int[] { 1, 10, 23, 9, 27 },
        new int[] { 3, 2, 17, 24, 11 },
        new int[] { 6, 11, 22, 5, 15 },
        new int[] { 7, 26, 28, 27, 8 },
        new int[] { 10, 23, 2, 15, 7 },
        new int[] { 13, 5, 19, 3, 9 },
        new int[] { 21, 23, 17, 16, 24 },
        new int[] { 4, 20, 6, 14, 14 },
        new int[] { 19, 4, 16, 24, 4 },
        new int[] { 27, 14, 28, 0, 17 },
        new int[] { 27, 20, 3, 8, 29 },
        new int[] { 2, 21, 0, 24, 26 },
        new int[] { 3, 2, 1, 23, 23 },
        new int[] { 11, 11, 15, 26, 17 },
        new int[] { 10, 26, 10, 8, 3 },
        new int[] { 3, 27, 11, 13, 28 },
        new int[] { 1, 29, 26, 3, 14 },
        new int[] { 20, 1, 10, 29, 8 },
        new int[] { 11, 25, 29, 28, 5 }
)));
```

*Output*

```
[211, 320, 295, 321, 303]
```

Comment: Hey, really useful answer! Is it the case that for loops are indeed the most efficient way to do this then?

Comment: @JamesL `Arrays.setAll()` uses a `for` loop too. It is slower though, because it has to do a *dynamic* method call into the Lambda expression for each value. JIT might eliminate that. Or not. --- But generally, if performance is *critical*, stay away from Streams and Lambda expressions. They are great for code clarity, but *may* have a performance impact.

Comment: Good to know. I'm coming from a background in R, where it's good practise to do everything in your power to avoid for loops - I suspect this difference comes from Java being compiled rather than dynamic.

Comment: @JamesL I don't know R, but website says *"R is a language and environment for statistical computing and graphics"*, so it seems like a lot of number-crunching to calculate statistics and to build image pixels, so parallel computing to desired, which is easy to achieve with functional computing. A `for` loop cannot be parallelized automatically, but Streams can be made parallel, and `setAll` has a `parallelSetAll` variant, and that's why Lambda's are desirable. A lambda might be slower, but if you throw 16+ CPUs at it, the result will definitely be much faster.

Comment: "we might as well keep the first half, even with such a guarantee" - Silently continuing when guarantees are not met is not healthy defensive programming. Code should usually throw in such cases.

Comment: @GonenI Depends on what you write in the javadoc of the method. Perhaps it is perfectly valid to sum up jagged arrays.